# how to update SwiftUIView withOut @State variable? and segmentation fault issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want increment a variable on Button action and show the value on Text. I can do it with `@State var i: Int = 0` variable. But I want to update the value from another class or swift file. So that file cannot access this variable unless it is static. But State can't be static as it fails build with `segmentation fault` error while building.

So I thought of making it a simple variable. Then updating from that class and then assigning it with a @State variable. But that is not happening because to update variable I'm using another static function on SwiftUIView struct as well.
I can update the static variable but I can't update the View.

heres the code for UIVIew:

```
struct ContentView: View {

//private var Arr = [String]()
@State static var x: Int = 0 //Causes segmentation fault, Removing static runs but can't access var x

static var testVar: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack{

        Text("Hello, Time: \(ContentView.testVar)")

        Button(action: {
            _ = timer().testMe() // calling other class method, is this Okay?


        }) {

        Text("Button")

            }
    }
}

static func bigGuy(){

    testVar += 1
    print("Hello You clicked this time: \(testVar)") // Without next line it can run and print with no issue.
    self.x = testVar // Don't want to use this, But how do I update View ?

}
```

So how do I update this simple view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use static, instead put that variable into view model and use instance of view model in both views, so one modifies it another presents it, like in below example

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var x: Int = 0
}

struct View1: View {
   @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
   var body: some View {
      Text("\(mv.x)")
   }
}

struct View2: View {
   @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
   var body: some View {
      Button("Modify") { self.mv.x += 1 }
   }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   let vm = ViewModel()
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
          View1(vm: self.vm)
          View2(vm: self.vm)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works. Can you please tell me how can I use this ObservedObject on another class? It has to conform `View`.

Comment: @Rifat, just pass it there as well, via dependency injection - in constructor, or via property, or method.